# Internationalization of a HTML + Markdown document (using RemarkJS)

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, markdown, remarkjs

I have many slides for a presentation made with [RemarkJS](https://remarkjs.com/). It is a HTML file `slides_fr.html` with a single `<textarea id="source">` containing the actual content in Markdown syntax (+ one or two specific markup tags to separate the slides with a page break), and one call to the JS library RemarkJS.

I am translating this document into English (I first duplicated `slides_fr.html` into `slides_en.html` and started to translate). Problem: each time I do improvement on the slides in the English version, I'll have to remodify the original file `slides_fr.html` to keep them in sync. In my experience, this rarely works well on the long-term. It would be better to have both versions in the same file, with markup for language.

Question: in order to avoid having two files `slides_fr.html` and `slides_en.html` like this that will ultimately never stay in sync:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<textarea id="source">
First slide

My presentation about XYZ

---

Second slide 

Hello world
</textarea>
<script src="https://remarkjs.com/downloads/remark-latest.min.js"></script><script>remark.create();</script>
</html>
```

**which options are there, using HTML or Javascript or Markdown-specific syntax to have both languages in the same file like this:**

```html
<textarea id="source">
First slide ||| Première diapositive

My presentation about XYZ  ||| Ma présentation à propos de XYZ

---

Second slide ||| Seconde diapositive

Hello ! ||| Bonjour 
</textarea>
<javascript>
chooseLanguage(document.getElementBydId('source'), 'en');    // there is surely a better solution
                                                             // than a parsing and splitting by '|||' ?
</javascript>
```

Comment: not sure if this would be any better, you could use CSS classes to mark which language applies to the text, like `.lang_en[Second slide]` `.lang_fr[Seconde diapositive]`, and than handle that with javascript. https://remarkjs.com/#12

Comment: (off topic) - thanks for letting me discover remarkjs, this is pretty useful.

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks! I have read https://remarkjs.com/#12 a few times but still not sure to understand how to use it... Would you have a demo example (in a runnable snippet) like your previous comment?

Comment: this shows how to use it: https://jsfiddle.net/k7au5oe3/ Of course this needs javascript (not provided in the snippet) to alternatively show / hide texts.

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks! Please post it as an answer, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

As a way to better organize localized texts, you could use CSS classes to mark which language applies to each text.

Remark provides a markdown extension called "Content classes" (https://remarkjs.com/#12), it's used to apply CSS classes to texts.

I think this feature could be exploited to wrap localized texts inside the markdown source, in this fashion:

- `.lang_en[Second slide]`
- `.lang_fr[Seconde diapositive]`
- `.lang_it[Seconda diapositiva]`

These will be transcripted in HTML as:

- `<span class="lang_en">Second slide</span>`
- `<span class="lang_fr">Seconde diapositive</span>`
- `<span class="lang_it">Seconda diapositiva</span>`

Once texts are structured this way, you can easily show / hide them via javascript and CSS.

This fiddle shows the Remark boilerplate localized in english and italian, adapted using the above strategy (javascript language switcher not provided in the snippet): https://jsfiddle.net/k7au5oe3/